# syslog ip ranges to specific files using `rsyslog`

Tags: linux, networking, unix, rsyslog

I have many Cisco / JunOS routers and switches that send logs to my Debian server, which uses `rsyslogd`.

How can I configure `rsyslogd` to send these router / switch logs to a specific file, based on their source IP address?  I do not want to pollute general system logs with these entries.

For instance:

- all routers in Chicago (source ip block: 172.17.25.0/24) to only log to `/var/log/net/chicago.log`.
- all routers in Dallas (source ip block 172.17.27.0/24) to only log to `/var/log/net/dallas.log`.
- Delete all `APF-3-RCV_UNSUPP_MSG` messages without logging them
- Send logs for 172.17.4.4 to a file named `/var/log/net/firewall.log`
- Forward firewall logs to 10.14.12.12 using UDP port 514

Finally, these logs should be rotated daily for up to 30 days and compressed.

---

NOTE:  I am [answering my own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**`rsyslogd` Configuration**

In `/etc/rsyslogd.conf`

```
# provides remote UDP syslog reception
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514

# If logging to an NFS mount, use these settings...
#    "OMFileFlushOnTXEnd off" avoids fsync on every write...
#     mount -o hard,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,noacl,noatime,nodiratime -t nfs
$OMFileIOBufferSize 768k
$OMFileAsyncWriting on
$OMFileFlushOnTXEnd off
$OMFileFlushInterval 10
$MainMsgQueueSize 100000


# kill all INTF-FLAP messages...
if $msg contains 'INTF-FLAP' then /dev/null
&~
## Cisco ACS Accounting...
if ($fromhost-ip=='172.17.16.20') and ($programname == 'CSCOacs_TACACS_Accounting') then /var/log/tacacs_acct.log
&~
## CiscoACS 5.4 TACACS Authentication
if ($fromhost-ip=='172.17.16.20') and ($programname == 'CSCOacs_Passed_Authentications') then /var/log/tacacs_auth.log
&~

# Logging for Chicago issues...
if $fromhost-ip startswith '172.17.25' then /var/log/net/chicago.log
& ~
# Logging for Dallas issues...
if $fromhost-ip startswith '172.17.27' then /var/log/net/dallas.log
& ~
# Logging for firewall...
if $fromhost-ip=='172.17.4.4' then @10.14.12.12
if $fromhost-ip=='172.17.4.4' then /var/log/net/firewall.log
& ~
```

Each of the `&~` entries prevents fall-through to the rest of the `rsyslog.conf` configuration; thus I won't see router syslog entries in `/var/log/messages`.

Touch all syslog files:

- `touch /var/log/net/chicago.log`
- `touch /var/log/net/dallas.log`
- `touch /var/log/net/firewall.log`

Restart `rsyslogd` with `/etc/init.d/rsyslogd restart`

**Log rotation**

In `/etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog`

```
/var/log/net/*.log
{
        copytruncate
        rotate 30
        daily
        missingok
        dateext
        notifempty
        delaycompress
        create root 664 root root
        compress
        maxage 31
        sharedscripts
        lastaction
                # RHEL: Use "/sbin/service rsyslog restart"
                # Debian / Ubuntu: Use "invoke-rc.d rsyslog reload > /dev/null"
                invoke-rc.d rsyslog reload > /dev/null
        endscript
}
```

Comment: Is there a way for an external program, like a python script, to read the value of `$fromhost-ip` for each log entry received by `rsyslogd`? The purpose here is to determine if the log entry comes from a certain ip address.

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is to [ensure you save `$fromhost-ip` in your rsyslog lines](https://superuser.com/a/835472/77053) and then parse `$fromhost-ip` out as your python script reads each log file line by line

Comment: Thanks, Mike. This is good advice. I'll have to look at `/etc/rsyslogd.conf` to make sure  `$fromhost-ip` is contained in the log message template.

Answer (score 4):

Also, I found this on the rsyslog wiki that could serve as future refernce for someone.

http://www.rsyslog.com/storing-messages-from-a-remote-system-into-a-specific-file/