# Authenticate Linux sshd with TACACS+ (Cisco ACS)

Tags: linux, ssh, cisco, authentication, tacacs+

Our network engineering team uses multiple linux servers for [syslog collection](https://serverfault.com/a/400294/78702), configuration backups, tftp, etc...

We want to use TACACS+ on a [Cisco ACS machine](http://www.cisco.com/go/acs) as our central authentication server where we can change passwords and account for user activity on these linux servers.  We also need to fall back to the static password in case the tacacs+ service is down.

How do we make [`sshd`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sshd&sektion=8) on CentOS authenticate against our [Cisco ACS](http://www.cisco.com/go/acs) tacacs+ server?

---

NOTE: I am [answering my own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Assumptions

- We are compiling `pam_tacplus.so` from v1.3.7 of the [pam_tacplus library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tacplus/)
- The Cisco ACS server is 192.0.2.27, and the secret tacacs+ key is `d0nttr3@d0nm3`

### Installation Instructions

1. Add the linux server's hostname / ip address into Cisco ACS and restart the Cisco ACS service
2. Download the [tacacs+ PAM module](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tacplus/) from SourceForge.
3. Install `pam` development package for your linux distro.  RHEL / CentOS call it `pam-devel`; Debian / Ubuntu call it `libpam-dev` (a virtual package name for `libpam0g-dev`).
4. Untar the tacacs+ `pam` module into a temporary working directory (`tar xvfz pam_tacplus-1.3.7.tar.gz`)
5. `cd` into the new folder created by `tar`.
6. As root: `./configure; make; make install`
7. As root, edit `/etc/pam.d/sshd`, and add this line as the first entry in the file:

   `auth       include      tacacs`
8. As root, create a new file called `/etc/pam.d/tacacs`:

```
    #%PAM-1.0
    auth       sufficient   /usr/local/lib/security/pam_tacplus.so debug server=192.0.2.27 secret=d0nttr3@d0nm3
    account    sufficient   /usr/local/lib/security/pam_tacplus.so debug server=192.0.2.27 secret=d0nttr3@d0nm3 service=shell protocol=ssh
    session    sufficient   /usr/local/lib/security/pam_tacplus.so debug server=192.0.2.27 secret=d0nttr3@d0nm3 service=shell protocol=ssh
```

### Per-Server / Per-user Instructions

As root on each server, create a local linux user account that matches the tacacs+ username for all required users.  The users can optionally use `passwd` to set their local password to whatever they like as a last resort; however, if they set a local password, they will be able to login locally at any time without `tacacs+` even if the service is available.

### pam_tacplus Service information

The details of how the `pam_tacplus.so` module works are in this [`pam-list` archived email](http://www.redhat.com/archives/pam-list/1998-October/msg00039.html)

Comment: how do we manage Linux user groups? I am not using CISCO as client, rather a linux box is client with pam_tacplus module.

Comment: @Mike Pennington: Do you know how to disable the local logins when a tacacs+ server is available? How should I arrange the rules above and do I need more rules for that?